# $N_p := \text{card}\{(x, y, z, t) \in (\textbf{F}_p)^4 : ax^4 + by^4 + z^2 + t^2 = 0\}$, special cases.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

What is $$N_p := \text{card}\{(x, y, z, t) \in (\textbf{F}_p)^4 : ax^4 + by^4 + z^2 + t^2 = 0\}$$in the following two cases?

1. When $ab \neq 0$ and $p = 2$.
2. When $ab = 0$.

Comment: do $a, b$ belong to $\mathbb F_p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Solution :** Let $$N_p(a,b):= \text{card}\{(x, y, z, t) \in (\textbf{F}_p)^4 : ax^4 + by^4 + z^2 + t^2 = 0\}$$
>   then:
>
> 1. If $p=2$ we have $N_p(a,b)=8$
> 2. If $ab=0$ but $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$ then $N_p(a,b)=p^3$
> 3. If $a=b=0$ then $N_p(0,0)=p^2$ when $p=3\mod 4$ and $N_p(0,0)=p^2(2p-1)$ if $p=1\mod 4$

I don't know what's your level in number theory but I will give you some ideas and you need to prove them:

**Case 1** when $p=2$ there is not need for the condition $ab\neq 0$ because the equation $ax^4+by^4+z^2+t^2=0$ is equivalent to $ax+by+z+t=0$ and hence $t=-(ax+by+z)$ so that you can choose any value you want for $(x,y,z)$ and $\cdots$. Finally $N_2(a,b)=2^3=8$

For the next cases we will assume WLOG that $b=0,a\neq 0$, the equation in this case is equivalent to $ax^4+z^2+t^2=0$ or $z^2+t^2=-ax^4$ :

**Case 2** This case (and the last one) is more subtle, assume that $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$:

*Lemma 1* if $e \in \mathbb{F}_p\backslash\{0\}$, then $z^2+t^2=e$ has $p+1$ solutions over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (this is simple to proof using elementary number theory)

This means that to every $x\in F_p\backslash \{0\}$, there exists $p+1$ solutions to the equation $z^2+t^2=-ax^4$ which is equivalent to our initial statement, now if $x=0$ the equation $z^2+t^2=0$ has only one solution $z=t=0$ because $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ finally :
$$N_p(a,0)=p(p-1)(p+1)+p $$ as :

- $p (p-1)$ is the number of $(x,y)\in F_p^2$ such that $ax^4\neq 0$, so that the equation $z^2+t^2=-ax^4$ has (p+1) solutions, this gives $p(p-1)(p+1)$ solutions to your original equation when $x\neq 0$.
- $p$ is the number of $(x,y)\in F_p^2$ such that $ax^4=0$ in which case the equation $z^2+t^2=-ax^4=0$ has only one solution, this gives $p\times 1$ solutions when $x=0$

**Case 3** in this case we assume that $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$, this would seem as a repetition, but I will provide all the elements so that the things which are not understood in this case the will be understood here.

*Lemma 2* if $e \in \mathbb{F}_p\backslash\{0\}$, then $z^2+t^2=e$ has $p-1$ solutions over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (again this is simple to proof using elementary number theory !)

This means that to every $x\in F_p\backslash \{0\}$, there exists $p-1$ solutions to the equation $z^2+t^2=-ax^4$ which is equivalent to our initial statement, now if $x=0$ the equation $z^2+t^2=0$ has this time $2p-1$ solutions $z=t=0$ because $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ finally :
$$N_p(a,0)=p(p-1)(p-1)+p(2p-1) $$ as :

- $p (p-1)$ is the number of $(x,y)\in F_p^2$ such that $ax^4\neq 0$, so that the equation $z^2+t^2=-ax^4$ has (p-1) solutions, this gives $p(p-1)(p-1)$ solutions to your original equation when $x\neq 0$.
- $p$ is the number of $(x,y)\in F_p^2$ such that $ax^4=0$ in which case the equation $z^2+t^2=-ax^4=0$ has $(2p-1)$ solution, this gives $p(2p-1)\times 1$ solutions when $x=0$.

Now if $a=b=0$ using the same reasoning, you can choose any value you want for $(x,y)$ which gives $p^2$ possible values, and the equation $z^2+t^2=0$ has either one solution ($p\equiv 3\mod 4$) or $2p-1)$ (if $p\equiv 1\mod 4$ )

Up to here I think I have proved all cases in the solution above, as a **note** I would mention that the same method will apply to the case where $ab\neq 0$.

Plaese if there is any mistake let me know